# RecyclerView smothScrollToPosition does not work in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, scrollto

I use RecyclerView in a ViewPager and when I want to scroll the 30th position of the current page it applies rather on another page.I have difine a method in the slider adapter call **scrollTo** in this method I call **smoothScrollToPosition**.The method **scrollTo** is call when I click on a button. 
I need help please.

**MainActivity**

```
    val pager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.view_pager)
    val adapter = SlideAdapter(this)

    pager.adapter = adapter

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
        adapter.scrollTo(30)
    }
```

**SliderAdapter**

```
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

fun scrollTo(position: Int) {
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
}

override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean = view == `object` as RelativeLayout

override fun getCount() = 5

override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.slide, container, false) as RelativeLayout


    val list = mutableListOf<String>()

    for (i in 0..50)
        list.add("Element $i")

    val viewAdapter = Adapter(context, list)
    val viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

    recyclerView.apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = viewManager
        adapter = viewAdapter
    }

    container.addView(view)

    return view
}

override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
    container.removeView(`object` as RelativeLayout)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method-
`linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(30,0)` on your `MainActivity`. Use `linearLayoutManager` which you are setting to `recylerview`.

**EDIT**
It happens because of viewpager loading more than one item at a time. you need to use the setprimary method in pageradadapter

`override fun setPrimaryItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, object: Any) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object)
 var mCurrentView = DataBindingUtil.getBinding<DcMediaPagerItemBinding>(object as View)}`

and use this mCurrentView to get your current recylerview item in activity

Comment: Hello ! I try it the result is the same. The problem is that when I call the scroll function I see no change in the current page. The change is applied to the next or the previous slide, I see it when change the page.

Comment: it happens because of viewpager loading more than one item at a time. you need to use the setprimary method in pageradadapter  override fun setPrimaryItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, `object`)
        mCurrentView = DataBindingUtil.getBinding<DcMediaPagerItemBinding>(`object` as View)
    
 } and use this mCurrentView to get your current recylerview item in activity